# Leetcode Move Zeroes: where are my bugs?

Tags: java, debugging

This is a easy question. [a link](https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/)
I just tried the simple insertionSorting-like method to solve it, however it failed.

```
public class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
         for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
             if(nums[i] == 0){
                    for(int j = i; j<nums.length-1; j++)
                    nums[j] = nums[j+1];
                nums[nums.length-1] = 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to debug my method?

Comment: I tried to use IDE to test my code. I think when the variable 'i' is increasing, the array nums is also changing, the elements after nums[i] is moving foward that causes error. It's like it traversals in a double speed in the out loop. However, I don't know how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

So i went through your code and re-wrote it to work. If you're moving zeroes to the end this should work perfectly fine for you. Cheers.
What this code does is iterates over your array until it hits a zero. Upon hitting a zero it loops, moving the 0 one place to the right over and over, switching spots with the value to the right of it, until the 0 is moved to the end of the array.

example: 5-loop cycle
[0,1,0,2,3] > [1,0,0,2,3] > [1,0,0,2,3] > [1,0,2,0,3] > [1,0,2,3,0]

```
int[] array = new int[] {0,1,0,12,3};

for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    if (array[x] == 0) {
        for (int y = x; y < array.length; y++) {
            if (y  != array.length-1) {

                // Store our replacement as temp
                int temp = array[y+1];

                // Move 0 to the right +1
                array[y+1] = array[y];

                // Set current position to what used to be right+1
                array[y] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, Thank you for your answer. I think your answer is somewhat like a bubbleSorting-like way to move '0's from front to end. However, Could use a insertionSorting-like way to do it?

Comment: Please don't dump code like this - it's not useful to people reading the question to simply see "here is code that works". Actually explain the issue, and how your code fixes it.

Comment: @AndyTurner First ever post, thanks for that feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share the javascript solution for the Move Zeroes problem from leetcode. It has O(n) time complexity.

#### Optimized for many zeroes

```
const snowball1 = nums => {
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  while (i<nums.length) {
    if(nums[i] != 0) {
      nums[j] = nums[i];
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  console.log(j);
  nums.fill(0, j);
  return nums;
}
```

#### Optimized for fewer zeroes

```
const snowball2 = nums => {
  for(let i = nums.length; i--;){
    if(nums[i]===0){
      nums.splice(i,1)
      nums.push(0);
    }
  }
  return nums
}
```

#### Example

```
console.log(snowball1([0,0,1,0,0,3,0,12,0]));
console.log(snowball2([0,1,0,3,12]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to write a very intuitive and easy approach to this problem. This problem can be solved using 2 indexes, one of which is the read pointer(rp) and the other is the write pointer(wp).

If rp reads a value of 0, it sets the wp to this index. The rp then keeps incrementing until it finds a non-zero value. If it does it overwrites the value at wp and this process fills the non-zero values in the beginning.

We then just need to fill the remaining spots with zeros till the end. Here's a short solution in python:

```
class Solution:
    def moveZeroes(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
        wp=rp=0
        while(rp<len(nums)):
            if(nums[rp]!=0):
                nums[wp]=nums[rp]
                wp+=1
            rp+=1
        for i in range(wp,len(nums)):
            nums[i]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the optimal solution wrt space O(N) and time O(1) below

```
public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
    // [0,1,0,3,12]
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] != 0) {
            int temp = nums[i];
            nums[i] = nums[j];
            nums[j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```